Modify html Editor with Toolbar Mode Ribbon
I hope you can help me, I want to add a letter to my HTMLEditor, but since I put the "Ribbon" template, any modification to the HtmlEditor will be replaced by the "Ribbon" template. How can you add letters to the ribbon? I want to add the lyrics Inter Medium.
I hope you can help me, I am using DevExpress 20.2, webforms.
I tried to add the internal source to the htmlEditor with CSS but the template replaces everything, that is, it is just added to the htmlEditor but once you put the template those attributes are not modified

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
